# Trigger error with column insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a trigger for insert.If one of the value is the same as that in the old table. then I print a message. Here is my code.

```
Create or replace  trigger TR_insert_act
After INSERT On ACTIVITIES
For each row 

DECLARE
l_act varchar(30);

Begin 

select Activity into l_act
From ACTIVITIES;

if(:new.Activity in l_act) then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('There is duplicate.'); 
end if;

end;
```

It is not compiled with the error on select of l_act, what to do please?

Comment: Are you trying to create a unique constraint?

Comment: THanks for reply. I dont't need constraint but just need to print a message if I found the value inserted already existed in the table.

Comment: You dont have a where condition.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `BEFORE` trigger, and a `WHERE` condition.

The `DBMS_OUTPUT` will not display the error though.

```
Create or replace  trigger TR_insert_act
before INSERT On ACTIVITIES
For each row 

l_act number;
Begin 

select count(1) into l_act
From ACTIVITIES
WHERE ACTIVITY = :new.Activity

if(l_act > 0 ) then
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
     num => -20000,
     msg => 'There is Duplicate');
end if;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I fix it. But DBMS_OUTPUT works in my case, I am using Oracle.